# Understanding MapReduce performance?

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I want to understand the map reduce performance better.

What dominates the performance of MapReduce algorithms implemented in Hadoop?

Is it the computation time, if there are a lot of data that has to be processed at a node, or is it the disk write and read times?

I have observed that disc write time takes a long time as compared to disc read time, when I ran some map reduce programs.

I want to know if the overhead of disc write is much greater than computation time(CPU time), needed to process a large collection of data at a node. Is CPU time trivial in comparison to I/O access?

The algorithm below is what happens at each reduce node:
I want to know if the CPU time for executing this algorithm is trivial compared to reading the input from HDFS and then after processing writing the output to the HDFS.

```
  Input : R is a multiset of records sorted by the increasing order of their sizes; each    record has been canonicalized by a global ordering O; a Jaccard similarity threshold t
  Output : All pairs of records hx, yi, such that sim(x, y) > t

  1 S <- null;
  2 Ii <- null (1 <= i <= |U|);
  3 for each x belongs to R do
  4 p <- |x| - t * |x| + 1;
  5 for i = 1 to p do
  6 w <- x[i];
  7 for each (y, j) belongs to Iw such
  that |y|>= t*|x| do /* size filtering on |y| */
  8 Calculate similarity s = (x intersection y) /* Similarity calculation*/ 
  9 if similarity>t
     S <- S U (x,y);
  10 Iw <- Iw Union {(x, i)}; /* index the current prefix */;

  11 return S
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general - it depends on the kind of processing you are doing. But it can be pointed out what takes time and consume resource aside of your code. 
We will go over MR job process and point out noticeable resource consumptions.
1. Read your split from HDFS. Unless local read optimization takes place - data passed via socket (CPU) and or network + Disk IO. MD5 is calculated also during the read.
1. Input Format. Input data should be chopped into Key Values for the Mapper. Taking into account that it is java it is always dynamic memory allocations and de-allocations. Parsing input usually takes CPU time. 
2. From Record Reader to mapper - no serious overhead. 
3. Mapper output is sorted and serialized (a lot of CPU) + local disk. 
4. Data is pulled by reducers from the mapper machines. A lot of networking. 
5. Data merged on reducer side. CPU + Disk. 
6. Output from reducer written to HDFS. x3 of data size disk IO + x2 network traffic because of replication.

In a nutshell 3,4,5 are usually most time and resource consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. It was highly helpful. I want to understand the performance on the basis of my code. Basically the processing that I am doing in my code is generating similar pairs, by using inverted index with some filtering strategy-Prefix Filter to reduce the length of the inverted index. I am wondering whether, this process is trivial in CPU time in comparison to the other factors  that you ve mentioned outside of the code to transfer the output generated by the processing done by the code. Pls help!

Comment: Do you have any links which explain in detail the MapReduce at a system level?

Comment: I think the best book is Hadoop Definitive Guide. For more details source code usually the only / best answer

Comment: I ve added the algorithm for what process happens in the each reduce node. I would like to know if this processing time is trivial in comparison to reading the input from HDFS and then writing it back to HDFS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess that your calculation takes serious part of time, so it is fine. In my last I would suggest simple test - run the same job w/o actual similarity calculation and measure time difference.

Answer (score 0):

This may shed some light on your understanding of the problem:

```
L1 cache reference                            0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                             5   ns
L2 cache reference                            7   ns             14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                            25   ns
Main memory reference                       100   ns             20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy              3,000   ns
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network        10,000   ns    0.01 ms
Read 4K randomly from SSD*              150,000   ns    0.15 ms
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory      250,000   ns    0.25 ms
Round trip within same datacenter       500,000   ns    0.5  ms
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*      1,000,000   ns    1    ms  4X memory
Disk seek                            10,000,000   ns   10    ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk     20,000,000   ns   20    ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA     150,000,000   ns  150    ms
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/2841832